# can't load library 'libcap.so.1.1" in openwrt

Tags: linux, openwrt

I have a tl-3020 router with openwrt. I installed tcpdump in ram (not enough space) but can't run it due to error mentioned in the title.

I've tried to re-install tcpdump and libcap

libcap that gets installed is v2.22-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading openwrt firmware fixed the problem (from 12.09 to 14.xx)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can go to the `/usr/lib` and `ls` to see if there is libcap.so.x.x.
and then you can link libpcap.so.x.x to what your package requires (libcap.so.1.1 in your situation) like:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libpcap.so.x.x /usr/lib/libpcap.so.1.1
```

sorry for the late answer :)
I came across the similar dilemma and Google brought me here. Maybe this trick works for guys like me.